# Find the subsequence which, once repeated, generate a given sequence

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

Given a sequence of size `N` which is the repetition of a unknown sub-sequence, how would you efficiently find the size `M` of the sub-sequence?

For instance :

```
input : 6651366513665136651366513 -> output : sequence of length 5 which is 66513
input : 11111111111111111111111111111 -> output : sequence of length 1 which is 1
input : 6651366513665136651366513665 -> output : sequence of length 5 which is 66513
```

- elements of the sequence are positive numbers, not just digits.
- `N` is not a multiple of `M` because the last sequence doesn't have to be complete. For instance `665` can be appended to first example.

The naive way is:

> assume the sub-sequence is of size `x`, test, if not correct increase
>   `x` and try again or output `x`

I am still designing another solution which doesnt have `O(N^2)` time complexity as the one above.

*note:* For the curious I am parsing a media file which index need to be built from stream analysis, I found out that the index follow a repetitive pattern. Rather than parsing a `2h` files I may parse one minute and guess the indexing for the next 1h59m.

Comment: The fourier transromation might help.

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete answer - but look up Rabin-Karp algorithm. It will help you improve the asymptotic complexity of your solution without changing the idea. Also the automata that Knuth-Morris-Pratt builds can be of help.

Comment: How many numbers does 1 minute of stream represent ?

Comment: @fjardon till `sum(x) = 48000 x 60`, x being each number, 48khz being the frequency. In a simple stream they all have the same size, so you don't need this algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Z algorithm](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107), suggested by ***Niklas B*** is the best match I found for my problem. 
Indeed it is defined as :

> `Zi(P)` = the length of the longest substring of P that starts at `i > 0`
>   and matches a prefix of P.

Given a z-algorithm the length of the sub-sequence is the index `k` which satisfy (if any) :

- `z[k] = n - k`
- `z[k] = max(z[i])`

For the input

`std::vector<int> v = { 6, 6, 5, 1, 3, 6, 6, 5, 1, 3, 6, 6, 5, 1, 3, 6, 6, 5 };`

the z-indexes are

`std::vector<int> z = { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,13, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0 };`

and `k = 5`

Answer (score 4):

Given a sequence `S`, to find the length of the period, you just have to find the second occurrence of `S` in `S+S`. For example:

Searching

```
6651366513665136651366513
```

in

```
66513665136651366513665136651366513665136651366513
```

Says that the second time the sequence occurs is in the index `5`. Given the original sequence has length = 25, you can see that it repeats 5 times.

You can use whatever substring search algorithm you want, e.g. KMP guarantees an O(n) complexity.

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to apply KMP to actually find `S` in `S+S`. The prefix function is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you missunderstood. input is `6651366513665136651366513`. Output should be `66513.`

Comment: @UmNyobe I think you may have misunderstood; take the first half of your input string, check where it occurs the second time, and the prefix before that position is the solution.

Comment: Except that the sequence may not align on the repetition boundary. The OP used this sequence: `6651366513665136651366513665` which doesn't fit your algorithm. In your example the sequence ends with the last `13` digits that make it work.

Comment: @IVlad I'm not sure if I understand. I always applied the KMP. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You only need to compute KMP's prefix function `pi[i] = length of the longest prefix of the string that is a suffix of string[1..i]`. Then, for each `i`, if `pi[i] > 0 && i - (i % pi[i]) == 0`, then the repeating prefix ends at `i`. It's still KMP and based on the same idea, my point was just that you don't need to actually double the string and run the full algorithm on the string and the doubled string.

Comment: It works almost the same using the [Z function](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107), which one could argue is somewhat easier to compute: The output is the first index i > 0 with n % i == 0 and z[i] = n - i (or n if no such index exists)

Comment: @JuanLopes can you improve your answer with Vlad input so I accept it? for instance I didnt spot at first KMP as being the algorithm you suggest.

Comment: @IVlad thanks for the clarification. I would upvote your answer if any.

Answer (score 0):

So the idea is you start with a minimum subsequence = 1 and a current index inside this subsequence= 0. Then you start comparing each character in the string. If the current character match your index inside the current minimum subsequence then you increment your current index subsequnce (% is to reset it back to zero after it reaches the end of the current subsequence size). If they don't match you set your window size to current index + 1 and reset your current index inside the window back to 0 and you start this process all over again. This runs in O(N).

```
    public void getMinSubsequenceLength(String s){
       int currentMinSubsequence=1;
       int currentIndexInSubsequence = 0;
       for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
           if(s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(currentIndexInSubsequence)){
               currentMinSubsequence = i+1;
               currentIndexInSubsequence = 0;
           } else {
               currentIndexInSubsequence = (currentIndexInSubsequence+1)%currentMinSubsequence;
           }
      }
       System.out.println(currentMinSubsequence);
}
```